# possible to show composition relationship in a diagram generated from PHP source code?

Tags: php, uml, visual-paradigm, nwire

i have tested several UML applications for whether they could show composition relationships in the UML diagrams generated form the PHP source code or not, and the result is they can't.

i know that this is a typical problem for PHP cause we don't declare a data type when we code, so it's difficult for the UML applications to know if an instance variable is a reference to an object or not.

i also tested nWire with the same result.

will there never be applications that could show us a complete map over all object relationships more than just inheritance?

i think it's a pity that you can't have a good view over all the relationships for an application. cause when i use an open source solution, i always want to know how the objects are related to each other.

maybe we could make comments for the instance variable telling the software that this is an reference to an object? but that would mean that the mapping software is using this solution.

i feel its a pity nWire/visual paradigm can't give us a complete map:(

Comment: I guess your best bet would be to look into existing PHP2XMI solutions if they can set the type from a PHPDoc annotation. The XMI can be imported in Umbrello or ArgoUML for instance.

Comment: Also, did you try Doxygen? Maybe that can do what you are looking for? Would be helpful if you give us a list of what you tried so far and maybe what you want the result to look like in UML.